# Getting the default font in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm running Python 3.6 and was wondering if there is a way to get the default font that Tkinter uses, more specifically the default font that the `Canvas` object uses when `canvas.create_text` is called.

Answer (score 1):

`idlelib/help.py` has this line:

```
    normalfont = self.findfont(['TkDefaultFont', 'arial', 'helvetica'])
```

where `findfont` is defined thusly:

```
def findfont(self, names):
    "Return name of first font family derived from names."
    for name in names:
        if name.lower() in (x.lower() for x in tkfont.names(root=self)):
            font = tkfont.Font(name=name, exists=True, root=self)
            return font.actual()['family']
        elif name.lower() in (x.lower()
                              for x in tkfont.families(root=self)):
            return name
```

(I did not write this.)

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/font.htm is the ultimate doc on font functions.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentaion [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm):

> Tk 8.0 automatically maps Courier, Helvetica, and Times to their corresponding native family names on all platforms.

I cannot find documentation that says what the default font for `canvas.create_text` would be but it should be one of the 3 listed in the above quote.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve your problem.

```
from tkinter import *


janela = Tk()
label = Label(janela)
print(label["font"])
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The default font used to create a text object on a canvas is "TkDefaultFont"

```
from tkinter import *
r = Tk()
c = Canvas(r)
c.pack()
id = c.create_text(10, 10, text='c')
def_font = c.itemconfig(id, 'font')[-2] # [-2] is default, [-1] is current
print(def_font, c.itemconfig(id)) # to see all the config info
```

If you wanted to modify that default font in place, you would use `nametofont()` to get access to the underlying font object and then manipulate it:

```
from tkinter import font
def_font_obj = font.nametofont(def_font)
def_font_obj.config(...)
```

If you don't want to customize a default font, you can create a new named font based on the current font and then modify that with

```
current_font = c.itemconfig(id, 'font')[-1] # or just c.itemcget(id, 'font')
new_named_font = font.Font(font=current_font).config(...)
```

then pass in the new_named_font as a font option to any widget config.